# validate a selectbox in a nested component

Tags: angular, devextreme

in my angular app I plan to use a selectbox on multiple forms. For this, I created a common component like this:

```html
<dx-select-box [dataSource]="companies"
               valueExpr="id"
               displayExpr="name"
               openOnFieldClick="true"
               deferRendering="false"
               noDataText="Nincs megjelenítendő adat"
               placeholder="Kérlek válassz"
               [value]="valueId">
</dx-select-box>
```

The corresponding ts file:

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { CompanyService } from '../../../services/masterdata/general/company.service';
import { Company } from '../../../models/masterdata/general/company.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'companyselectbox',
  templateUrl: './companyselectbox.component.html',
  styleUrls: []
})
export class CompanySelectBoxComponent {

  @Input() valueId: number;

  companies: Company[];

  constructor(private service: CompanyService) {
    this.service.getCompanies().subscribe(companies => this.companies = companies);
  }
}
```

This works, I get the values in the select box.

Now, I can use it in other components like this:

```html
<form (submit)="onFormSubmit($event)" method="post">
  <dx-form #plantForm id="form" [formData]="plant" validationGroup="valgroup" labelLocation="top">
    <dxi-item dataField="id" [visible]="false">
    </dxi-item>
    <dxi-item dataField="companyId" [label]="{text: 'Gazdasági egység'}">
      <companyselectbox [valueId]="companyId"></companyselectbox>
      <dxi-validation-rule type="required" message="A mező kitöltése kötelező"></dxi-validation-rule>
    </dxi-item>
    <dxi-item dataField="code" [label]="{text: 'Gyárkód'}">
      <dxi-validation-rule type="required" message="A mező kitöltése kötelező"></dxi-validation-rule>
      <dxi-validation-rule type="async" message="Ilyen nevű gyár már létezik" [validationCallback]="checkCode">
      </dxi-validation-rule>
    </dxi-item>
    <dxi-item dataField="location" [label]="{text: 'Székhely'}">
      <dxi-validation-rule type="required" message="A mező kitöltése kötelező"></dxi-validation-rule>
    </dxi-item>
    <dxi-item itemType="group">
      <div *dxTemplate>
        <div style="text-align: right">
          <dx-button text="Mentés" [width]="100" type="default" stylingMode="contained"
                     [useSubmitBehavior]="true" style="margin-right: 5px" validationGroup="valgroup"></dx-button>
          <dx-button text="Mégsem" [width]="100" type="normal" (click)="closeButtonClick()"></dx-button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </dxi-item>
  </dx-form>
</form>
```

Every imports, etc. are on place, no error while compiling.

Look for the `companyselectbox` in the markup (if I could make it bold...no, the bold button doesn't make it bold). The select box appears correct on the form and I get the values in it.

I attach to the `dxi-item` a required `dxi-validation-rule`. If I hit then the save button on the form and left the select box empty, there is no required mark showing. But if I delete the `companyselectbox` component and replace with the markup in the `companyselectbox` component, the required mark is showing.

So, the question is, how do I get the validation work with the `companyselectbox`? I wouldn't like to repeat the `dx-select-box` component on each forms.

Comment: I wouldn't use external validation. Rather I'd move it to the select box itself and use NgModel which supports an online pattern attribute for validation https://dev.to/jwp/ngmodel-internals-2m9f